# Trigger that updates stock levels after a sale

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a trigger that will automatically update my stock levels after a sale has taken place i.e. after I input a new entry in my sales table.

Relevant tables and columns: 
Product.Quantity_held (Represents Stock)
Sales.Quantity (Represents sales)

The below is where I am so far and this successfully creates the trigger, however when I insert details for a new sale, the Product.Quantity_held figure does not update.

Any ideas why please?

```
DELIMITER //

create trigger StockUpdate

after update on sales 

for each row begin 

insert into Product 

set action = 'update', 

Quantity_held = (Quantity_held - New.Quantity);

END;
```

Comment: You are inserting after Update query, While i guess you need Update after Insert Query. Right?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and triggers are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the table and filter for the correct product:

```
create trigger StockUpdate after update on sales 
for each row
begin 
    update Product 
        set action = 'update', 
             Quantity_held = (Quantity_held - New.Quantity)
        where product_id = new.product_id
end;
```

You probably need `insert` and `delete` triggers as well if this has any hope of being accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need below by just swapping your INSERT and UPDATE keywords -

```
DELIMITER //
create trigger StockUpdate
after insert on sales
for each row begin 
update Product 
set action = 'update', 
    Quantity_held = (Quantity_held - New.Quantity);
END;
```